# Better way of doing object conversion from one type to another?

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-beanutils

I am converting objects that are coming through an `API` request body to `JPA` objects as below.

```
public class Converter {

   public static <T> Object from(T request) {
        if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(request))
            return null;
        if(request instanceof ConfigRequest) {
            Config config = new Config(); //create JPA object to copy properties into from request body
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(request, config);
            return config;
        }
        if(request instanceof DecisionRequest) {
            Decision decision = new Decision();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(request, decision);
            return decision;
        }
        .......
    }
}
```

I have around 15 different request objects to work with (which will lead to 15 `if` blocks).

Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same goal with `Generics` or some other way I may have missed out?

TIA.

Comment: Each `if` statements could be moved to an entry in a Map<Class<?>, MappingHandler>, where a `MappingHandler` instance would contain the body of an `if` statement.  The method is currently static, but if dependency injection was used, the class would never have to change since new handlers would be registered somewhere else as part of the injected Map.

Comment: Handle each conversion _completely_ separately; don't use null; don't use BeanUtils and copy every field individually.

Comment: Why do you recommend to not use BeanUtils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I have around 15 different request objects to work with (which will lead to 15 `if` blocks).*
>
> *Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same goal with `Generics` or some other way I may have missed out? ..."*

Rather than *generics*, utilize a class hierarchy.

Delegate each *if-statement* from the corresponding class.

```java
abstract class Request {
    abstract Object get();
    boolean isConfig() { return this instanceof ConfigRequest; }
    boolean isDecision() { return this instanceof DecisionRequest; }
}

class ConfigRequest extends Request {
    @Override
    Config get() {
        Config config = new Config(); //create JPA object to copy properties into from request body
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(request, config);
        return config;
    }
}

class DecisionRequest extends Request {
    @Override
    Decision get() {
        Decision decision = new Decision();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(request, decision);
        return decision;
    }
}
```

Then, simply return the *get* call.

```java
public static Object from(Request request) {
    if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(request)) return null;
    return request.get();
}
```

Comment: This looks more elegant than what I did. Thanks!

Comment: @nehacharya, I crossed the names here, _Config_ should be _ConfigRequest_.  I'll make an edit.